# Make a responsive table within WordPress.

Tags: html, wordpress, css, responsive-design

I know there are a lot of questions already posted on this stack about responsive tables but trust me I've been through all of them and haven't found the solution to my problem. Or maybe I didn't know exactly what I was looking for which is why I'm forced to ask a question here.

The problem at hand is pretty simple. I'm making a wordpress site. I didn't exactly like the theme pricing table so I took up the challenge to make my own. Here is the link to my Wordpress page where I need this table: 
http://www.desklers.com/uae/undergraduate-packages

So my table is fine but I'm having trouble making it responsive. 
The following is the html I'm putting in the raw html widget of my visual composer in wordpress:

```
<style type="text/css">    
/*General styles*/




/*Features table------------------------------------------------------------*/
@media screen and (max-width: 640px) {
    .features-table {
        overflow-x: auto;
        display: block;
    }
}
.features-table
{
font-family:'Open Sans';

  margin: 0 auto;
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 0;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff;
  color: #2a2a2a;
  background: #fafafa;  
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fff, #eaeaea, #fff); /* Firefox 3.6 */
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear,center bottom,center top,from(#fff),color-stop(0.5, #eaeaea),to(#fff)); 
}

#check {
color: #26CCA4;
font-size:20px;
}
#cross {
color: #E74A4A;
font-size: 20px;
}
.features-table td
{
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  padding: 0 20px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #cdcdcd;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 white;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 white;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 white;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-align: center;
}

/*Body*/
.features-table tbody td
{
  text-align: center;


}

.features-table tbody td:first-child
{
  width: auto;
  text-align: left;
}

.features-table td:nth-child(2), .features-table td:nth-child(3), .features-table td:nth-child(4)
{
  background: #DADADA;
  background: #E3E3E3;
  border-right: 1px solid white;
}


.features-table tr:nth-child(even)
{
  background: #e7f3d4;  
  background: #E3E3E3;
}

/*Header*/
.features-table thead td
{
   font-family: 'Open Sans';
   font-size: 16;
   color: white;
   line-height:16px;
   font-weight:100;
   font-variant:small-caps;

  -moz-border-radius-topright: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 10px; 
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-top: 1px solid #eaeaea; 
}

.features-table thead td:first-child
{
  border-top: none;
}

/*Footer*/
.features-table tfoot td
{

  -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 10px; 
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #dadada;
}

.features-table tfoot td:first-child
{
  border-bottom: none;
}




    </style> 

    <div id="main">

        <table class="features-table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td style="background-color:#000000;"><div class="box">
   <div class="ribbon"><span>FEATURED</span></div><p style=" color: white; font-size:30px; font-weight:100;"> Unlimited</p></div></td>
                        <td style="background-color:#229BAA;"><p style=" color: white; font-size:30px; font-weight:100;">Premium</p></td>
                        <td style="background-color:#FEFEFE;"><p style=" color: black; font-size:30px; font-weight:100;">Basic</p></td>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tfoot>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td><a class="mk-button outline-btn-dark button-562cf9ad35f16 light outline-dimension medium pointed   " target="_self" href="http://www.desklers.com/uae/product/undergraduate-admission/"><span style="font-size:15px;">Get This Plan</span></a></td>
                        <td><a class="mk-button outline-btn-dark button-562cf9ad35f16 light outline-dimension medium pointed   " target="_self" href="http://www.desklers.com/uae/product/undergraduate-admission/"><span style="font-size:15px;">Get This Plan</span></a></td>
                        <td><a class="mk-button outline-btn-dark button-562cf9ad35f16 light outline-dimension medium pointed   " target="_self" href="http://www.desklers.com/uae/product/undergraduate-admission/"><span style="font-size:15px;">Get This Plan</span></a></td>
                    </tr>
                </tfoot>                    
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td id="price" style="background-color:#000000;">$5000</td>
                        <td id="price" style="background-color:#2BC2D5;">$3000</td>
                        <td id="price" style="background-color:#FEFEFE; color:black;">$1500</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr id="one">
                        <td>Number of Colleges Universities</td>
                        <td>20</td>
                        <td>10</td>
                        <td>5</td>          
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Number of Countries you can apply</td>
                        <td>Unlimited</td>
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td>1</td>          
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Money Back Guarantee</td>
                        <td><i class="mk-moon-checkmark" id="check"></i></td>
                        <td><i class="mk-moon-checkmark" id="check"></i></td>
                        <td><i class="mk-icon-remove" id="cross"></i></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>High school planning</td>
                        <td><i class="mk-moon-checkmark" id="check"></i></td>
                        <td><i class="mk-icon-remove" id="cross"></i></td>
                        <td><i class="mk-icon-remove" id="cross"></i></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Academic advising and coaching</td>
                        <td><i class="mk-moon-checkmark" id="check"></i></td>
                        <td><i class="mk-icon-remove" id="cross"></i></td>
                        <td><i class="mk-icon-remove" id="cross"></i></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Transcript evaluations</td>
                        <td><i class="mk-moon-checkmark" id="check"></i></td>
                        <td><i class="mk-icon-remove" id="cross"></i></td>
                        <td><i class="mk-icon-remove" id="cross"></i></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Admission Documents Handling</td>
                        <td><i class="mk-moon-checkmark" id="check"></i></td>
                        <td><i class="mk-moon-checkmark" id="check"></i></td>
                        <td><i class="mk-icon-remove" id="cross"></i></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Guidance in SAT, ACT and Subject Tests</td>
                        <td><i class="mk-moon-checkmark" id="check"></i></td>
                        <td><i class="mk-moon-checkmark" id="check"></i></td>
                        <td><i class="mk-icon-remove" id="cross"></i></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>SAT, ACT and Subject Tests Preparation and Coaching</td>
                        <td><i class="mk-moon-checkmark" id="check"></i></td>
                        <td><i class="mk-icon-remove" id="cross"></i></td>
                        <td><i class="mk-icon-remove" id="cross"></i></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Athletic Recruitment</td>
                        <td><i class="mk-moon-checkmark" id="check"></i></td>
                        <td><i class="mk-icon-remove" id="cross"></i></td>
                        <td><i class="mk-icon-remove" id="cross"></i></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Guidance in selecting best fit colleges</td>
                        <td><i class="mk-moon-checkmark" id="check"></i></td>
                        <td><i class="mk-moon-checkmark" id="check"></i></td>
                        <td><i class="mk-moon-checkmark" id="check"></i></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Developing and finalizing a college list</td>
                        <td><i class="mk-moon-checkmark" id="check"></i></td>
                        <td><i class="mk-moon-checkmark" id="check"></i></td>
                        <td><i class="mk-icon-remove" id="cross"></i></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Guidance and coaching about how to write winning Application Essays and Supplements</td>
                        <td><i class="mk-moon-checkmark" id="check"></i></td>
                        <td><i class="mk-moon-checkmark" id="check"></i></td>
                        <td><i class="mk-moon-checkmark" id="check"></i></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Proof reading and feedback on College Essays and Supplements</td>
                        <td><i class="mk-moon-checkmark" id="check"></i></td>
                        <td><i class="mk-moon-checkmark" id="check"></i></td>
                        <td><i class="mk-moon-checkmark" id="check"></i></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Discussing, helping, developing and finalizing College Ideas for Essays and Supplements</td>
                        <td><i class="mk-moon-checkmark" id="check"></i></td>
                        <td><i class="mk-icon-remove" id="cross"></i></td>
                        <td><i class="mk-icon-remove" id="cross"></i></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Proof Reading and finalizing Application Essays and Supplements</td>
                        <td><i class="mk-moon-checkmark" id="check"></i></td>
                        <td><i class="mk-icon-remove" id="cross"></i></td>
                        <td><i class="mk-icon-remove" id="cross"></i></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Letters of Recommendation</td>
                        <td><i class="mk-moon-checkmark" id="check"></i></td>
                        <td><i class="mk-moon-checkmark" id="check"></i></td>
                        <td><i class="mk-icon-remove" id="cross"></i></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Leadership opportunities</td>
                        <td><i class="mk-moon-checkmark" id="check"></i></td>
                        <td><i class="mk-moon-checkmark" id="check"></i></td>
                        <td><i class="mk-icon-remove" id="cross"></i></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Summer strategies</td>
                        <td><i class="mk-moon-checkmark" id="check"></i></td>
                        <td><i class="mk-moon-checkmark" id="check"></i></td>
                        <td><i class="mk-icon-remove" id="cross"></i></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Social Work Opportunities</td>
                        <td><i class="mk-moon-checkmark" id="check"></i></td>
                        <td><i class="mk-moon-checkmark" id="check"></i></td>
                        <td><i class="mk-icon-remove" id="cross"></i></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Extra-Curricular activities guidance</td>
                        <td><i class="mk-moon-checkmark" id="check"></i></td>
                        <td><i class="mk-moon-checkmark" id="check"></i></td>
                        <td><i class="mk-icon-remove" id="cross"></i></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Guidance in Scholarship applications</td>
                        <td><i class="mk-moon-checkmark" id="check"></i></td>
                        <td><i class="mk-moon-checkmark" id="check"></i></td>
                        <td><i class="mk-moon-checkmark" id="check"></i></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Assistance in filling scholarship applications</td>
                        <td><i class="mk-moon-checkmark" id="check"></i></td>
                        <td><i class="mk-icon-remove" id="cross"></i></td>
                        <td><i class="mk-icon-remove" id="cross"></i></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Guidance in CSS and other financial aid applications</td>
                        <td><i class="mk-moon-checkmark" id="check"></i></td>
                        <td><i class="mk-moon-checkmark" id="check"></i></td>
                        <td><i class="mk-moon-checkmark" id="check"></i></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Assistance in filling CSS and other financial aid applications</td>
                        <td><i class="mk-moon-checkmark" id="check"></i></td>
                        <td><i class="mk-icon-remove" id="cross"></i></td>
                        <td><i class="mk-icon-remove" id="cross"></i></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Follow-ups</td>
                        <td><i class="mk-moon-checkmark" id="check"></i></td>
                        <td><i class="mk-icon-remove" id="cross"></i></td>
                        <td><i class="mk-icon-remove" id="cross"></i></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Visa Application Guidance and Handling</td>
                        <td><i class="mk-moon-checkmark" id="check"></i></td>
                        <td><i class="mk-icon-remove" id="cross"></i></td>
                        <td><i class="mk-icon-remove" id="cross"></i></td>
                    </tr>



                </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
 </body>
```

Here is the JSfiddle to my code: https://jsfiddle.net/d96q4h3d/

Using the media query, and setting overflow-x to auto, I have been able to make my table drag-able along x-axis. However I want the table to appear in full when the page loads so that the user can see the full table. Then he can zoom in any particular part if he wants to look at it closely.

Any help on the problem would be appreciated. I have done a lot of research on google but have been unable to find a particular solution that explains how I can view the complete table on the page.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First remove `white-space: nowrap;`

now you would have to make the table max-width:(the size that you want)

like in the example the max-width is 900px : https://jsfiddle.net/d96q4h3d/7/

if you would like to make the table smaller, you would have to reduce the size of the `<thead>` tags, and the "#price" id like this

```
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    .features-table thead p {
    font-size: 20px !important;
    }
    #price {
    font-size: 20px;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .features-table thead p {
    font-size: 15px !important;
    }
    #price {
    font-size: 15px;
    }
    .features-table td{
    padding: 0px 10px;
    }
}
```

And always put your @media screen in the end of the of the bottom, not on the top!

Comment: By far this seems to be the best working solution! Thanks a bunch! :D 
Only one problem, the featured ribbon on unlimited does not seem to resize along with the table in the fiddle. Do you have any ideas on how i can fix that?

Comment: you dont need to resize it, be cause its already small, my opinion is that you nees to move it a bit, and add some height to the <thead> tag so that it doesnt overflow the text too much. Here you are the update: https://jsfiddle.net/d96q4h3d/8/ (you could also remove it from @media screen lower the 600px by display:none)

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered adopting a [WordPress theme](https://wordpress.org/themes/search/bootstrap/) based on the [Bootstrap toolkit](http://getbootstrap.com/css/)?

If you do that you can use [this sort of pattern to emit your table](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables), and it will be responsive without all kinds of hassles.

```
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table">
     your table
  </table>
</div>
```

Bootstrap is a really good way to get responsive tables and other ui elements; its developers have done a great job debugging things for all sorts of browsers.

Comment: The thing is I'm doing this website for a client. I'm not a pro myself yet so experimenting and learning along the way! Therefore the client chose the theme for his site and paid for it so I had to go with it.

Comment: This solution makes the table (kinda) responsive. Just essentially sets `overflow-x: auto;` which makes you able to scroll the table horizontally.

Comment: I'm already able to do that. What I need is for the table to resize and show completely on the screen on a small screen device and from there the user can zoom in on the table however he wants. overflow-x is not the solution to this problem. I will need to turn it off and find another way to make the table resize according to screen size. :/

Answer (score 1):

It's a hard problem since tables are inherently not responsive. There are many different ways of achieving a desired result. Many include the use of javascript.

Here's a good round-up of different techniques, including a really clever pure-CSS one (#8), which is my favourite.

http://exisweb.net/responsive-table-plugins-and-patterns

**EDIT:**

Since you need the entire table to be visible on mobile devices, a suitable solution for this case might be specifically:

https://github.com/ghepting/jquery-responsive-tables - [DEMO](http://ghepting.github.io/jquery-responsive-tables/)

Comment: I've already been to this page. #8 is not effective because even that will not show the complete table on the screen on a small screen device. Since I'm not very comfortable with JS, I'm looking for a CSS solution. But obviously if I can't find one there will have to opt to JS :(

Comment: Then how about just scaling the fonts at small device widths with media queries ?